# Python 3 tkinter: check when an entry has the value of a string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am pretty new to tkinter and I'm wondering if or how this is possible:
I would like to start a function as soon as the entry's value equals the '*target*' string.
I currently have a simple window with:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")

val = StringVar()
target = "test this sentence"

ent = Entry(root , width = 75 , textvariable=val)
ent.pack()

typed = Label(root , textvariable=val)
typed.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Is this going to be possible?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `trace` method of `StringVar`,

```
val = StringVar()
val.trace('w', callback)
```

Then you can write your function like,

```
def callback(*args):
    if val.get() == target:
        print 'it worked!'
```

`'w'` signifies the mode and just means that the function is called when content is written.